# Gem uninstall permission denied @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm having problems with my gems install. I believe I installed it with sudo. I tried to uninstall using:

```
gem uninstall -aIx
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:75:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/bundler-1.10.5.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)
```

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: ....`sudo gem uninstall` ....?

Comment: `sudo` temporarily escalates the user's permissions to root. You have to use `sudo` to escalate to root to undo anything done previously.